# Sending an arrow key event to the window via Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a simple script to re-map the WASD keys to send up/left/down/right key events to the window. I'm using the latest Firefox version and Greasemonkey.

This is the script I have right now, and I've tried numerous variations of it, plus some other methods I found online. Nothing works.

```
// ==UserScript==
//
// @grant          unsafeWindow
//
// ==/UserScript==

function KeyCheck(e)
{
  //alert(e.keyCode);
  var key = 0;
  if (e.keyCode == 87) 
  {
    key = 38;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 65)
  {
    key = 37;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 83)
  {
    key = 40;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 68)
  {
    key = 39;
  }
    var ev = document.createEvent ('KeyboardEvent');
    ev.initKeyEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, key, key);
  unsafeWindow.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

unsafeWindow.addEventListener('keydown', KeyCheck, true);
```

All I need is one simple function that can successfully post a key event to the window or document. Manually scrolling the page is not an option here (because I want to make sure that other scripts that may be running on the page that detect the arrow keys are triggered)

Comment: Oh my lord, what function has 10 parameters (why would someone do that)? That's a bit extensive.  Anyways, hope your problem gets solved.  :)

Comment: This may not me possible using Greasemonkey. Does the target page use jQuery? Flash? iFrames?

Comment: There is no target page, I'm trying to write it as a general extension to how I broswse things like forums, galleries, etc. That's why I want to send key events, as opposed to anything else - because in some cases the arrow keys scroll the page, while in other cases they have a in-page effect.

Comment: @BrockAdams Noticed you've handled a LOT of userscript questions.  The solution to this one may be interesting to throw into your toolbox.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, your answer appears to be just injecting the OP's code.  The Op's code will only work in select circumstances, injected or not.  In general, browsers do not respond well to generated keyboard events and you may also need to emulate a natural sequence. Also, Flash or iFrames can complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

OK -- I figured out a way to pull it off.

Tested under Firefox and GreaseMonkey -- I didn't test it under Chrome.

**Edit** Tested under Chrome and TamperMonkey. Keypresses were registered as well.  I don't believe the regular built-in Chrome user-scripts have unsafeWindow and they are much more limited.

In short, the code won't work as user-script.

So, we cheat the system and turn the user script into a regular script and inject it into the page itself.

Now, it doesn't actually work and scroll -- but it does catch the key events and throws up the alert.

**EDIT: NOTES**

Its been my experience that GreaseMonkey is pretty much paranoid about letting anything accidentally slip from the unsafe window into the very sandboxed and protected world of user-scripts.

Events, in particular, are kind of tricky.  An event registered to unsafeWindow cannot and will not bubble back up to GreaseMonkey -- something which has caused me no small amount of grief.

```
// ==UserScript==
//
// @grant          unsafeWindow
// @include   http://*/*
// @include   https://*/*
//
// ==/UserScript==


var head = unsafeWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head') [0],
script = unsafeWindow.document.createElement('script');

// The magic is here.
// We turn the script into a string which will get parsed be the JS compiler
// when it is added to the unsafeWindow.document.

var scriptTxt = '(' + fn + ')()';

script[script.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = scriptTxt;
head.appendChild(script);

// This is just a wrapper to hold things.    
function fn() {

  function KeyCheck(e)
  {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    var key = 0;
    if (e.keyCode == 87)
    {
      key = 38;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 65)
    {
      key = 37;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 83)
    {
      key = 40;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 68)
    {
      key = 39;
    }
    var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    ev.initKeyEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, key, key);
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
  window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyCheck, true);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort there. I guess the way Firefox (at the least) has been set up, even doing this won't trigger scrolling or other page events linked to the normal arrow keys. Unfortunately, it seems like there is no solution thru Greasemonkey. I may have to use some outside tool like AutoHotkeys.